# Erro ao remover acentos

Tags: javascript, node.js, acentuação

Estou com um código em javascript para remover acentos, ele funciona com qualquer acento, menos com a crase, e pelo código deveria funcionar com a crase também. Não consigo encontrar o bug.

```
var teste = "Çaptúra de Tela 2016-04-27 às 18.21.24.png à à";


function removerAcentos( s ) {
        var map={"â":"a","Â":"A","à":"a","À":"A","á":"a","Á":"A","ã":"a","Ã":"A","ê":"e","Ê":"E","è":"e","È":"E","é":"e","É":"E","î":"i","Î":"I","ì":"i","Ì":"I","í":"i","Í":"I","õ":"o","Õ":"O","ô":"o","Ô":"O","ò":"o","Ò":"O","ó":"o","Ó":"O","ü":"u","Ü":"U","û":"u","Û":"U","ú":"u","Ú":"U","ù":"u","Ù":"U","ç":"c","Ç":"C"};

        console.log('remove acentos',s.replace(/[\W\[\] ]/g,function(a){return map[a]||a}));

        return s.replace(/[\W\[\] ]/g,function(a){return map[a]||a});
    }

  console.log(removerAcentos(teste));
```

Answer (score 6):

Ainda que não aparente esses `à` não são o mesmo caractere... dá uma olhada a esta comparação: https://www.diffchecker.com/2t62nhqv, e se usares o mesmo o teu código (aparentemente igual)  já funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/qecnk7Lk/

O que acontece é que o UNICODE tem duas possibilidades, ou o caracter completo com acento, ou duas entidades... uma a letra e outra o [acento como complemento](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm).

Em ES6 já é possível normalizar isto com [`.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) e o código fica bem simples. A regex é uma combinacão dos códigos dos [acentos possíveis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks):

```js
var teste = "Çaptúra de Tela 2016-04-27 às 18.21.24.png à à";

function removerAcentos(s) {
  return s.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
}

console.log(removerAcentos(teste));
```

Para suportar browsers antigos também podes usar [esta biblioteca](https://github.com/walling/unorm) que faz o mesmo que o ES6 trás. Ficando assim: https://jsfiddle.net/qjwcmo1v/

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/walling/unorm/master/lib/unorm.js"></script>
```