# Buscar DDD pela cidade

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que tem números de telefones. Para facilitar a vida dos usuários, gostaria de retornar o DDD que não consta em alguns números.

Alguém conhece alguma API, ou algo do tipo para retornar o DDD de acordo com a cidade.

Comment: API não, mas é uma coisa que dá para montar fácil na mão. Vc tem [sites](http://dddcidade.com.br/) que listam todas as cidades por ddd. Daí, é só sopiar e colar para uma tabela e implementar um objeto Json, um conjunto de listas, dicionários, ou a estrutura de dados que preferir. Se puder publicar isso como uma biblioteca independente ajuda toda a comunidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe o http://ddd.pricez.com.br e pode usar com PHP ou jQuery (ou qualquer meio de consulta com HTTP)

### Consulta DDD com jQuery:

```js
var siglaEstado = "am";
var url = "https://ddd.pricez.com.br/estados/" + siglaEstado.toLowerCase();

$.getJSON(url).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (xhr, codigo, c) {
    console.log( "error:", xhr.readyState, codigo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Então no `.done` basta filtra pelo que desejar, por questão de haver acentos talvez seja interessante implementar [**`String.normalize`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize), como no exemplo em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148229/3635

por exemplo:

```js
function removeAcentos(s) {
  return s.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
}
    
function consultar(siglaEstado, resposta) {
    var url = "https://ddd.pricez.com.br/estados/" + siglaEstado.toLowerCase();

    $.getJSON(url).done(function (data) {
        resposta(data);
    }).fail(function (xhr, codigo, c) {
        resposta(false);
    });
}

(function () {
    var consultando = false;
    var qualDDD = document.getElementById("qual-ddd");
    var consultaDDD = document.getElementById("consulta-ddd");
    
    consultaDDD.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //cancela o form normal
    
        consultando = true;//Bloqueia novas consultas até terminar

        qualDDD.textContent = "Consultando...";

        var estado = consultaDDD.querySelector("[name=estado]").value;
         
        var cidade = removeAcentos( consultaDDD.querySelector("[name=cidade]").value );
         
         consultar(estado, function (dados) {

             if (!dados) {
                  qualDDD.textContent = "Falha na requisição";
                  return;
             }
             
             if (!dados.count) {
                  qualDDD.textContent = "estado não encontrado";
                  return;
             }

             for (var i = 0, j = dados.payload.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (cidade === removeAcentos(dados.payload[i].cidade)) {
                     qualDDD.textContent = "O DDD é " + dados.payload[i].ddd;
                }
             }

             consultando = false;
         });
    });
})();
```

```css
#qual-ddd {
    font-size: 19pt;
    padding: 15px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="qual-ddd"></div>

<form id="consulta-ddd">
    <select name="estado">
       <option value="am">Amazonas</option>
       <option value="sp" selected>São Paulo</option>
    </select>

    <input name="cidade" value="São Paulo">

    <button>Consultar</button>
</form>
```

### Consulta DDD com PHP:

Para obter os dados com PHP pode usar `curl` ou `file_get_contents`, no exemplo vou aplicar curl, porque file_get_contents exige certas configurações quantos aos certificados de seguraça e muitos servidores desabilitam o allow_url_open no php.ini.

Em PHP deve ficar assim mais ou menos:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['cidade']{0}, $_POST['estado']{0})) {
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

    //Codifica para url os dados
    $estado = urlencode($estado);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ddd.pricez.com.br/estados/' . $estado);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept:application/json' ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if($data === false) {
        echo 'Erro ao executar o CURL: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($httpcode !== 200) {
            echo 'Erro ao requisitar o servidor';
            $data = null;
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    function simplificaRemoveAcentos($texto)
    {
        $encode = mb_detect_encoding($texto, mb_detect_order(), true);
        $texto =  'ASCII' === $encode ? $texto: iconv($encode, 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $texto);

        return trim(strtolower(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\s]#i', '', $texto)));
    }

    if ($data) {
        $ddd = false;

        $payload = json_decode($data)->payload;
        $cidade = simplificaRemoveAcentos($cidade);

        foreach ($payload as $value) {
            if (simplificaRemoveAcentos($value->cidade) === $cidade) {
                $ddd = $value->ddd;
            }
        }

        if ($ddd) {
            echo 'O DDD é ', $ddd;
        } else {
            echo 'Cidade não encontrada';
        }
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="estado">
       <option value="am">Amazonas</option>
       <option value="sp" selected>São Paulo</option>
    </select>

    <input name="cidade" value="São Paulo">

    <button>Consultar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado...

Comment: Parece que o ddd.pricez.com.br está offline há algumas semanas. Minha segunda opção é o republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep=seu_cep&formato=json ou https://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/75144460

Answer (score -4):

Usa isso:

```html
<select id="uf" name="uf">
<option value='' disabled selected>DDD</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
<option value='24'>24</option>
<option value='27'>27</option>
<option value='28'>28</option>
<option value='31'>31</option>
<option value='32'>32</option>
<option value='33'>33</option>
<option value='34'>34</option>
<option value='35'>35</option>
<option value='37'>37</option>
<option value='38'>38</option>
<option value='41'>41</option>
<option value='42'>42</option>
<option value='43'>43</option>
<option value='44'>44</option>
<option value='45'>45</option>
<option value='46'>46</option>
<option value='47'>47</option>
<option value='48'>48</option>
<option value='49'>49</option>
<option value='51'>51</option>
<option value='53'>53</option>
<option value='54'>54</option>
<option value='55'>55</option>
<option value='61'>61</option>
<option value='62'>62</option>
<option value='63'>63</option>
<option value='64'>64</option>
<option value='65'>65</option>
<option value='66'>66</option>
<option value='67'>67</option>
<option value='68'>68</option>
<option value='69'>69</option>
<option value='71'>71</option>
<option value='73'>73</option>
<option value='74'>74</option>
<option value='75'>75</option>
<option value='77'>77</option>
<option value='79'>79</option>
<option value='81'>81</option>
<option value='82'>82</option>
<option value='83'>83</option>
<option value='84'>84</option>
<option value='85'>85</option>
<option value='86'>86</option>
<option value='87'>87</option>
<option value='88'>88</option>
<option value='89'>89</option>
<option value='91'>91</option>
<option value='92'>92</option>
<option value='93'>93</option>
<option value='94'>94</option>
<option value='95'>95</option>
<option value='96'>96</option>
<option value='97'>97</option>
<option value='98'>98</option>
<option value='99'>99</option>
</select>
```

Utilizando o cep: 08150-300 como exemplo, o retorno da consulta é:

```js
{"payload": {
  "bairro": "Jardim Robru",
  "cep": "08150300",
  "cidade": "S\u00e3o Paulo",
  "cidade_info": {
    "area_km2": "1521,11",
    "codigo_ibge": "3550308"
  },
  "ddd": 11,
  "estado": "SP",
  "estado_info": {
    "area_km2": "248.221,996",
    "codigo_ibge": "35",
    "nome": "S\u00e3o Paulo"
  },
  "logradouro": "Rua Severino Jos\u00e9 Fernandes"
 }
}
```

Realizo a chamada no evento blur do campo CEP

```js
$("#cep").on("blur",function(e){
        //Limpo os campos...
        $("#endereco, #bairro, #cidade, #uf, #ddd").val("");
        var cepConsulta = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
        if (cepConsulta != "") {
          showModal("Aguarde<br>Consultando endereço...");
          $.getJSON("https://ddd.pricez.com.br/cep/"+cepConsulta).done(function (data) {
              if(data.payload.bairro === undefined){
                alert("Não foi possível localizar o endereço\nVerifique o CEP digitado");
                $("#cep").focus();
                return false;
              }
              //Preencho os campos
              $("#endereco").val(data.payload.logradouro);
              $("#bairro").val(data.payload.bairro);
              $("#cidade").val(data.payload.cidade);
              $("#uf").val(data.payload.estado);
              //aqui vai selecionar o DDD do select anterior
              $("#ddd").val(data.payload.ddd);
          }).fail(function (xhr, codigo, c) {
              console.log( "error:", xhr.readyState, codigo);
          }).always(function() {
            closeModal();
          });
        }
```

Comment: E como seria essa API? E como selecionar o DDD de acordo com o CEP, com esse código que você sugeriu?

Comment: Melhorei o código acima amigo, com um exemplo de uso