# Gostaria de pesquisar não importando a acentuação do título

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="divBusca">
                  <input class="txtBusca" type="text" name="Tópicos"
                  id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar por item..."/>
                  <br><br><br>
          </div>
          <br>
        <ul id="ulItens">
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Agenda </a></li>

                 <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <button> Relatórios </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório comparação </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório de pedidos </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório grafico pico vendas </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório grafico pico por qtd </a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <button> eCommerce </button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Todos Pedidos </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Total itens </a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar</a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar manual </a></li> 
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Faturamento </a></li> 
                    </ul>
                  </li>
        </ul>
```

Gostaria de buscar por "Relatorio" e aparecesse o "Relatório". Deve ser extremamente simples porém não estou sabendo encaixar no código.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function()
            {
                $("#txtBusca").keyup(function()
                {
                    var texto = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $("#ulItens li").css({"display":"block"}).addClass("pushy-submenu-open");

                    if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) == 0)
                    {

                        $("#ulItens li").removeClass("pushy-submenu-open");

                    }

                    $("#ulItens li").each(function()
                    {
                        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) < 0)
                        {
                            $(this).css({"display":"none"});

                        }

                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Se remover a acentuação de todas as palavras na lista e depois procurar por Relatorio consegue ;)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148229/3774

Comment: Para mim não resolveria pois o menu necessariamente tem que ter a acentuação

Comment: Utilize expressões regulares para remover caracteres com acentuação e especiais das duas strings antes de compara-las (jogue o valor para variáveis distintas, à fim de não remover o conteúdo original delas). - Bom exemplo em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3995/58027

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uma função (função `tiraAcentos` abaixo) que retorna a string sem os acentos (bem como já converte para minúsculas). Use a função tanto no valor do campo quanto na string a ser buscada:

```js
$(function(){
               
   function tiraAcentos(i){
      
      i = i.toLowerCase().trim();
   
      var acentos = "ãáàâäéèêëíìîïõóòôöúùûüç",
      sem_acentos = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc";
      
      for(var x=0; x<i.length; x++){
         var str_pos = acentos.indexOf(i.substr(x,1));
         if(~str_pos) i = i.replace(acentos.charAt(str_pos),sem_acentos.charAt(str_pos));
      }
      
      return i;
   }

   $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
      var texto = tiraAcentos($(this).val());
      $("#ulItens li").css({"display":"block"}).addClass("pushy-submenu-open");
      if(tiraAcentos($(this).text()).indexOf(texto) == 0){
         $("#ulItens li").removeClass("pushy-submenu-open");
      }
   
      $("#ulItens li").each(function(){
         if(tiraAcentos($(this).text()).indexOf(texto) < 0){
            $(this).css({"display":"none"});
         }
   
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divBusca">
   <input class="txtBusca" type="text" name="Tópicos" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Buscar por item..."/>
   <br><br><br>
</div>
<br>
<ul id="ulItens">
   <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Agenda </a></li>

   <li class="pushy-submenu">
      <button> Relatórios </button>
      <ul>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório comparação </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório de pedidos </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório grafico pico vendas </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Relatório grafico pico por qtd </a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="pushy-submenu">
      <button> eCommerce </button>
      <ul>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Todos Pedidos </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Total itens </a></li>
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar</a></li> 
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Importar manual </a></li> 
         <li class="pushy-link"><a href=""> Faturamento </a></li> 
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```