# Remover acento e caracteres especiais do nome de um arquivo pdf

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de na hora que fosse selecionado o arquivo pdf, se ele vier com acento que seja retirado pela função retira_acentos().

```
<tr>
    <th nowrap>Arquivo PDF*:&nbsp;</th>
    <td><input type="file" name="arquivoPDF" id="arquivoPDF" class="CampoTexto1" onchange="retira_acentos(this)"/></td>
</tr>
```

Como faço para ler o nome do arquivo e depois passar ele na função retirar_acentos e mostrar na tela para o usuário?

```
if(!validaExtensaoArquivo(retira_acentos($('arquivoPDF')), "pdf")){
    bootbox.alert("O arquivo referente ao campo 'Arquivo PDF' deve possuír extensão pdf.");
    $('btoAlterar').disabled = false;
    return false;
}   

function retira_acentos(str) 
{
    com_acento = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ";
    sem_acento = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYRsBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuybyr";
    novastr="";
    for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        troca=false;
        for (a=0; a<com_acento.length; a++) {
            if (str.substr(i,1)==com_acento.substr(a,1)) {
                novastr+=sem_acento.substr(a,1);
                troca=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (troca==false) {
            novastr+=str.substr(i,1);
        }
    }
    return novastr;
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Erro ao remover acentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148180/3774)

Comment: Você quer selecionar um arquivo no `input` e ao selecionar já remover os acentos? Antes de enviar pro `back-end`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @PedroHenrique ! Ele deveria mostrar na tela do front ja sem os acentos para o usuário e enviar para o back também.

Comment: @JoãoVictorLimaRocha, acredito que não é possível alterar o nome do arquivo em um `input.file`, mas você pode recuperar o nome para usar, o que você pretende fazer?

Comment: Preciso remover os acentos do nome do arquivo antes de enviar para o backend. @PedroHenrique

Comment: Não tem como enviar o arquivo com o nome alterado.

Comment: Você pode mostrar o nome do arquivo pro usuário sem acentos e no `back-end` apenas remove os acentos.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um evento de `change` no elemento de seleção de um arquivo, quando for selecionado algum arquivo, será recuperado o nome desse arquivo e mostrado na tela para o usuário.

```js
// Evento ao selecionar um arquivo
$("#file").change(function(){
    const nome = $(this).prop('files')[0].name; // recupera nome do arquivo
    $("#nome_ori").text(nome); // atribui ao span#nome_ori o nome original do arquivo
    $("#nome_rep").text(retira_acentos(nome)); // atribui ao span#nome_rep o nome sem acentos do arquivo
});

// Função de trocar acentos
function retira_acentos(str) 
{
    com_acento = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ";
    sem_acento = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYRsBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuybyr";
    novastr="";
    for(i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        troca=false;
        for (a=0; a<com_acento.length; a++) {
            if (str.substr(i,1)==com_acento.substr(a,1)) {
                novastr+=sem_acento.substr(a,1);
                troca=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (troca==false) {
            novastr+=str.substr(i,1);
        }
    }
    return novastr;
}
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Selecione um arquivo</label>
  <input type="file" id="file">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Nome arquivo original:</label>
  <span id="nome_ori"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Nome arquivo sem acento:</label>
  <span id="nome_rep"></span>
</div>
```

---

> Com isso basta agora fazer o mesmo no `back-end`, recuperar o nome do
>   arquivo e trocar os caracteres com acentos existente para sem acentos.

---

#### Referência: [Change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)